# How to Add No Index tag to category path product urls in magento?

Tags: category, magento-1

We want to **add no index robots meta tag for all those category path product pages**:

> **www.example.com/Category/productpage**

**Actual product page**:

> **www.example.com/productpage**

category path product page is:

> **www.example.com/Category/productpage**

We have already added canonical tags all the category path product pages

> **"wwww.example.com/Category/productpage"**

by following the first option mentioned in this article

> **https://www.hallaminternet.com/how-to-add-canonical-tags-in-magento/**

[image]

Now we have to add no index robots tag to all those category path product pages

> **www.example.com/Category/productpage**

because search engines are indexing the category path product pages, rather than exact product page urls. This is effecting our seo and traffic.

Please give us suggestion that will help us to solve this issue.